# Running Background Processes in Websites

Tags: service-worker, web-notifications

I'm interested in running background processes once users go to a website. My question is very broad but for example I'd like to poll a JSON API every minute or so and send the user a web notification anytime the response from the JSON API changes. Is this possible with service workers? How can I accomplish this?

If this is possible, then is it possible that I can run a WebAssembly file in a service worker so that the application is running even when the website is not open?

Or can I run a service worker to grab the latest version of a site and have it cached so that the website loads immediately on their next visit?

Comment: Please check this link may hope helpful for you https://jsfiddle.net/1g88x8z8/

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to register a persistent background process that continues running indefinitely after a user visits a web site.

It is possible to register a service worker when visiting a web site. The service worker will not run most of the time, but can be "woken up" by an event like an incoming [push notification](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications), even if the user doesn't currently have a page open associated with your web app.

By design, when a service worker is woken up in that sort of fashion, it will only run for a short period of time before it's terminated. It is also expected to [show a notification](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications#display_a_notification) to the user letting them know that something is going on. Service workers that are woken up via `push` events but which do not show notifications might find themselves disabled by a browser.